# Using Jest to test useEffect that updates state to pass into child component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm quite new to writing tests with jest and React Testing Library, and have hit a bit of a hurdle with some code coverage in a file.

The component I am testing is as follows.

```
const Alerts = () => {
  const [header, setHeader] = useState();

  // get state from redux store
  const search = useSelector(selectSearch);

  const getAlertsHeader = async () => {
    const { searchStats } = search;
    const { totalSaved, indexes, location } = searchStats;

    const searchIndexes = indexes.map((i) => i.id);

    const defaultSubtitle = 'Organise your searches.';

    const data = {
      title: `Searches (${totalSaved})`,
      subTitle: location ? `Searches For ${location}` : defaultSubtitle,
      searchIndexes,
    };

    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    const getHeader = async () => {
      if (isMounted && search?.searchStats) return getAlertsHeader();
      return null;
    };

    getHeader().then((h) => isMounted && h && setHeader(h));

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header
        title={header?.title}
        subTitle={header?.subTitle}
        searchIndexes={header?.searchIndexes}
        loading={!header}
      />
      <div>Alerts Page</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

My current test is fairly basic, just ensuring that it renders.

```
describe('Alerts', () => {
  test('it should render without error', async () => {
    // renderWithStore just wraps component in store provider
    const { container } = renderWithStore(<Alerts />);

    expect(container).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

My code coverage does not cover the `getAlertsHeader` function or the `useEffect` hook. And I'm unsure how to test to get coverage of those lines?

I know I can trigger a change to the `redux` store state that is the dependency of the `useEffect` with

```
act(() => {
  store.dispatch(
    setSavedSearches({
      data: {
        ...
      },
    }),
  );
});
```

To possibly check against the state/value that gets returned in the `useEffect` via `getAlertsHeader`, but unsure how to?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For what it's worth, we are not currently using enzyme, so a method without using that package would be preferred.

Comment: what if you create your own hook from your `useEffect` and test it separately?

Comment: What exactly would that look like, and would I need to do that for every similar implementation of a `useEffect` hook updating a local state value?